# Render components for all routes except one specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am writing a React app with multiple routes, I have header and footer components as well which will be visible on all components. But now I want to hide footer component for a specific route.

```
<Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path={routes.home} exact component={Home} />
          <Route path={routes.office} component={Office} />
          <Route path={routes.park} exact component={Park} />
          ...
          ...
          ...
          <Route path={routes.shopping} component={Shopping} />
        </Switch>
    <Footer />
```

so header and footer component are always rendered. But now I want footer component visible for all routes except shopping, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this without using render props or the *useRouteMatch* hook is to use one specific route for the page where you don't want the header or footer, and a "catch-all" route that will match all other routes. You can then use a nested Switch statement to handle the rest of your applications routes.

In the example below I have a '/auth' route which will only render the Auth component and nothing else. In the rest of the application (after the user had logged in) I want the Navbar and Sidebar components to show up on all routes, so they live inside the 'catch-all' Route which does not have a 'path' property set. This means it will trigger for all routes except '/auth' (because /auth is declared before it).

```
<Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      {/* The route which will not render the sidebar and navbar components */}
      <Route path="/auth">
        <Auth/>
      </Route>
      {/* Catch-all route that will match everything except /auth and render Sidebar and Navbar on all pages */}
      <Route>
        <Sidebar/>
        <Navbar/>
        {/* The rest of the routes for the application */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/projects">
            <Projects/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, one way would be:

First pass the routes you want to hide via props as an array:

```
<Router>
    <Header hideRoutes={[routes.shopping]} />
    <Switch>
        <Route path={routes.home} exact component={Home} />
        <Route path={routes.office} component={Office} />
        <Route path={routes.park} exact component={Park} />
        {/*moreRoutes*/}
        <Route path={routes.shopping} component={Shopping} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer hideRoutes={[routes.shopping]} />
</Router>
```

Then in your Header and Footer components check the pathname for the hide route and then hide when appropriate by passing back an empty div

```
const Header = (props)=>{
    const {hideRoutes , location:{pathname}} = props
    let shouldHide = false
    hideRoutes.some(hideRoute => {
        if (pathname === hideRoute)
            return shouldHide = true
    })
    if (shouldHide) 
        return <div/>

    //proceed to return header
}
```